# How to order by 2 columns with empty field?

Tags: sql

I have a question about ordering a SQL table. 
I can't find a solution on stack or google. 
My table seems as follows:

```
Code    Name        Referent    Phone        Email         
-----------------------------------------------------------
501     Paul                    0234343      paul@paul.com   
502     Andreas                 03245345     Andreas@andreas.com
501                 Robert      027766543    robert@robert.com
504     Samuel                  0935345345   samuel@sam.com
503     Emmanuel                0935345345   emanuel@emm.com
```

I want to order first by Name and after by Code but I want the same codes under the same code raw as follows:

```
Code    Name        Referent    Phone        Email         
-----------------------------------------------------------
502     Andreas                 03245345     Andreas@andreas.com
503     Emmanuel                0935345345   emanuel@emm.com
501     Paul                    0234343      paul@paul.com   
501                 Robert      027766543    robert@robert.com
504     Samuel                  0935345345   samuel@sam.com
```

As you can see I want to have for column Code with 501 first the item with Name column not empty and after the column with 501 code and empty Name column.

@Rob Using 
       COALESCE(Name, Referent), 
        Code 
I get rows ordered by Name alphabetically as I want but not also by code for example I have:

```
Code    Name        Referent                   
---------------------------------
502     Andreas      NULL
501     Caesar       NULL               
503     Emmanuel     NULL
504     Marcus       NULL 
501     NULL        Marcel
```

As you can see 501 with null name not appears under Caesar but under 504 (Marcus), alphabetically it seems that Referent column follows Name column with 'M' chars.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support `MAX OVER`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `COALESCE` function in your `ORDER BY`. Assuming the table is called `Names` the following query would achieve this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Names]
ORDER
BY      COALESCE(Name, Referent), 
        Code
```

What the [`COALESCE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) is doing is basically saying, "return the value from the first of the columns listed as parameters that is not null". This is then being used by the `ORDER BY` to determine the order of the rows that are returned.

This does pre-suppose that the data is stored as a NULL, rather than an empty string. If it's actually stored as an empty string, then you can work in the [`NULLIF` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) to achieve this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Names]
ORDER
BY      COALESCE(NULLIF(Name, ''), NULLIF(Referent, '')),
        Code
```

I've used the following test harness to put these queries together:

```
CREATE TABLE [Names]
(
    Code INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Referent NVARCHAR(100),
    Phone NVARCHAR(100),
    Email NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT
INTO    [Names]
        (
            Code,
            Name,
            Referent,
            Phone,
            Email
        )
VALUES  ( 501, 'Paul', NULL, '0234343', 'paul@paul.com' ),
        ( 502, 'Andreas', NULL, '03245345', 'Andreas@andreas.com' ),
        ( 501, NULL, 'Robert', '027766543', 'robert@robert.com' ),
        ( 504, 'Samuel', NULL, '0935345345', 'sam@samuel.com' ),
        ( 503, 'Emmanuel', NULL, '0935345345', 'emanuel@emm.com')
```

Comment: @Aominè, If you're referring to `ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(Name, ''), NULLIF(Referent, ''))` then yes. Bear in mind that the `COALESCE` has to be fed the result of each of the functions inside it. If the value for `Name` for a given record is '' then `NULLIF(Name, '')` will return NULL, meaning that COALESCE will have to evaluate the `NULLIF(Referent, '')` - I don't know if it will *always* be evaluated (i.e. SQL will work out the result for the 2nd NULLIF for every row, if that's what you were asking?

Comment: COALESCE(Name, Referent), Code doesn't works as I want.
With COALESCE 501 with null Name isn't below the first 501 code but It follows the order of Referent column.

Comment: @Rob I see. makes sense. I was mixed up between the `ISNULL` and `NULLIF`.

Comment: @ezechiele2517, could you give an example that doesn't give you what you're asking for, to make it clearer for me? =) The output I get exactly matches what you've shown as "expected" so I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing! =)

Comment: @Rob Using COALESCE I get rows ordered by Name alphabetically as I want but not also by code for example I have:
Code    Name        Referent                   
-----------------------------------------------------------
502     Andreas                     
503     Emmanuel                
501     Paul                    
501                 Marcel

Comment: @Rob I explained the COALESCE problem in my first post. Please see it.
Thanks

Comment: @ezechiele2517, I'm not sure I can suggest a solution, I'm afraid. The rules you want to apply for the ordering aren't 100% clear to me. You appear to want to have the data sorted by `Name` until the (alphabetical) first entry for that name is received, then to have all the other entries for that *code* sorted alphabetically by `Name` and then `Referent` under that item? (Which could be me getting the complete wrong end of the stick!)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works but perhaps you can order with CONCAT

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(Name, Referent)
```

Never tried that and I cannot test it now. So sorry if it is nonsens :)

Should Work, if you separate the Strings Using Pipe, at least something ordered Low, Like ' impossible '

```
Concat(Name,'     ',Referent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to order by two columns at a time.

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable 
 ORDER BY Name, Code
```

OR

```
 SELECT *, (Name + Code) AS NameCode FROM MyTable 
 ORDER BY NameCode
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregates it's simple:

```
order by max(name) over (partition by code)
  ,name nulls last
```

Otherwise you need a Scalar Subquery (which might be very inefficient):

```
from mytable as t1
...
order by (select max(name) from mytable as t2 where t1.code = t2.code)
  ,name nulls last
```